# SqlDataReader отсутствует считанная строка, но HasRow true

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
      using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
        if (reader.Read())
        {

        }
```

После инициализации св-во HasRow=true, но строки нет.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Возможно вы не правильно тракуете полученый результат. Ридер может вам отдать одну строку, а не все, из вашего скрина ничего не понятно. Если вы не понимаете как работает HasRows - читайте msdn (про свойство Results в msdn не идет речь, и не гарантируется там результат). Если понимаете - отредактируйте вопрос так, что б было понятно в чём проблема. MSDN - вот http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows

Comment: Сначало вызывается метод Read, потом читаются значения полей. Наоборот - не работает. А вообще есть справка с примерами.

Comment: Я в курсе, что строка заполняется после вызова метода Read(), но отладчик сообщает "Перечисление не дало результатов", хотя св-во HasRow сообщает, что данные есть. Возможно отладчик не предусматривает отображение считанной (текущей строки).

Comment: Значения полей хранятся в отдельных "чанках", которые недокументированые, и находятся в защищенной зоне (private/protected). То что вы спрашиваете (Result View) относится к  IEnumerable, который находится в этом обьекте. Несмотря на то, что в интерфейс заложена поддержка IEnumerable, в справке не указано какой именно тип перечисления отдаётся. Скорее всего интерфейс возвращает просто пусто, поэтому выводится сообщение "Перечисление не дало результатов". Но нигде в документации не написано что нужно использовать даное перечисление.

Answer (score 0):

`DataReader` не моментально считывает все данные, а возвращает их по 1 строчки на каждый вызов метода `Read`.

На вашем скришоте я вижу, что вы поставили точку останова на месте, где должно было произойти считывание.

Comment: До момента считывания.

Comment: после вызова read() тоже пусто

Comment: @gru34ik по идее, Result View должен открываться только в том случае, если есть перечислитель, а его нету у Reader'a...

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 0):

Не смотря на то, что отладчик после вызова метода Read() не отображает содержимое считанной строки с сообщением "Перечисление не дало результатов" данные все же есть. При попытке присвоить var v=reader["id"]; переменная заполнена корректным значением